# not able to get anything in output in python ssh

Tags: python, python-2.7, paramiko

I am trying to connect to remote server and then try to login the sql server in that machine. however i am not getting any ouput of this script

```
import paramiko

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy() )
ssh.connect(hostname='172.18.109.244', username='bgf', password='bgf')
print "Logged In to EMS"
cmd = 'mysql -uroot -root'

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
stdin.write("show databases;")
stdin.write('\n')
stdin.flush()
print stdout.read()
```

Comment: `read()` consumes content to EOF. There is no EOF here because MySQL is still open. The way answer is to not just flush stdin, but close it. The hard answer is to switch to use `pxssh` or another tool with `expect`-like functionality.

Comment: i tried to use pexpect but its throwing the error of can not use spawn

Comment: @MukeshNarwal you can try my answer. just pass the query to MySQL connection and it will work like boom :)

Comment: @MukeshNarwal, if you can't find anything about that error already in the knowledgebase, feel free to ask another question about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment by @Charles,

> read() consumes content to EOF. There is no EOF here because MySQL is
>   still open. The easy answer is to not just flush stdin, but close it.

you can not do that because MySQL is still open and your script will hang there. So if you just want to get the database, then pass the query to MySQL connection and will work fine :).

```
    import paramiko
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy() )
    ssh.connect(hostname='172.18.109.244', username='somuser',password='bgf')
    print "Logged In to EMS"
    cmd = 'mysql -h somehost.example.com -uroot -proot -e \'show databases;\''

    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
    # stdin.write("show databases;")
    stdin.write('\n')
    stdin.flush()
    print stdout.read()
```

Comment: what will be the host address?

Comment: the host address is your MySQL host, where you want to connect. if the DB is on localhost then ignore it if it some remote host then add the host.

Comment: thanks it worked, but still not able to run the commands in interactive way as i passing only cmd in this solution. Sorry for silly question but still new to programming

Comment: This is limitation here because mysql shell, you can try Fabric http://www.fabfile.org/

Comment: Heh. Oops -- I meant to say "easy answer", but was typing on a phone; don't know how it came out as "way answer".

Comment: hahah Thanks @CharlesDuffy I quoted your comment without any changes ;)